# 1_event set notation

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, martingale

I do not understand the notation as given here:
[image]

The source for the image is page 17 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02101.pdf) after equation 18.

I understand the first subset notation but what does 1_\e_t mean?

Comment: It's the indicator random variable.

Comment: What is the meaning of an indicator random variable for a sigma field?

Comment: A random variable that takes on value 1 when the event happens, and 0 when it doesn't.  So, if one event is a subset of the other, its indicator is less than the other's.

Comment: Picture not showing for me!

Comment: Pl click this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSPUR.png